# SpriteKit Example without Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to write the iOS Game Example that uses SpritKit in Swift, which is provided with Xcode only in code. That means I don’t want to use the GameScene.sks, actions.sks and the main.storyboard. I know how to write it without storyboard, but I can’t get it working without the .sks files. Can you say what I must change or can you provide me with a full project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will first need to have a `View Controller`. You can adjust the properties how you would like them. Here is mine:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: View Controller overrides
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view = SKView(frame: view.bounds)

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Initialise the scene
            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size) // <-- IMPORTANT: Initialise your first scene (as you have no .sks)

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)

            // Scene properties
            view.showsPhysics = false
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

}
```

Then, you create a class for your first scene. Mine is called `GameScene` which was initialised in the view controller. Make sure this is a subclass of `SKScene`. It will look something like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    /* All Scene logic (which you could extend to multiple files) */

}
```

---

If you have any questions, let me know :)